# What is an inductive proof that every set is either infinite, in bijection with a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, or empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, infinity

In a math class I took the professor said that for every set $S$, exactly one of the following is true:

- $S$ is infinite
- $S$ is in bijection with the set $\{m\in\mathbb{N}\  |\  {m\leq{n}}\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$
- $S$ is the empty set

He said the proof is "a careful induction." But what exactly would this induction be? I'm not quite sure what we would be inducting on -- perhaps number of elements in the set? But then the logic of the proof seems circular . . .

**Note:** The definition of an infinite set $S$ that we were given in this class is that there exists an injective mapping  $\ f: S \rightarrow S$ which is not surjective. The definition of a finite set we were given is a set that is not infinite.

E.g., for $\mathbb{N}$ we can use the mapping $f: n \mapsto n+1$. This mapping is injective since $m+1=n+1$ implies $m=n$, but it is not surjective since there is no natural number $n$ such that $f(n)=1$. Therefore, $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Of course, there are various infinite cardinalities -- $\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1$, etc. -- but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: What's your definition of finite? Infinite?

Comment: It really depends on the assumptions you make, and the definition of "infinite".

Comment: The definition of an infinite set we learned in the class above mentioned is a set for which there exists an injection mapping the set into itself which is not surjective, i.e., it is one-to-one not onto. Will add this definition into the question, but come on, does this question really deserve a vote down? Please let me know if there are other definitions of infinite that conflict with this one.

Comment: Now that the OP has added which definition of "infinite" they're using, I disagree with the vote to close.

Comment: I edited "an injective mapping... that is not injective" to "an injective mapping that is not surjective."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, re: definitions of infinite-ness: this is indeed *not* the usual definition. Usually, a set is finite iff it is in bijection with $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ for some $n$ (or empty). What you've described is [Dedekind finiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

That said, here's an outline of the proof:

Suppose $A$ is not empty, or in bijection with any $\{1, 2, . . .n\}$. Then (exercise - show by induction that we never get "stuck") we can pick a sequence of elements $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . . , a_n, . . .$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) of distinct elements of $A$. Now consider the following function $f: A\rightarrow A$:

- $f(a_i)=a_{i+1}$.
- If $b\not=a_i$ for any $i$, then $f(b)=b$.

Exercise: use $f$ to show that $A$ is infinite.

Perhaps surprisingly, this proof implicitly uses the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) - specifically, in the construction of the sequence of $a_i$s. It is consistent with ZF ( = set theory without choice) that there is an infinite set which is **not** Dedekind-infinite.

---

How we are relying on the axiom of choice above? Well, we show by induction (this does **not** use Choice) that, in constructing the $a_i$s, we never "get stuck": that given any sequence $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n$ of distinct elements of $A$, there is some $a_{n+1}\in A$ which is not equal to any of $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n$. However, this just says that arbitrarily long finite strings of distinct elements of $A$ exist. Without the axiom of choice, we can't show that an *infinitely* long string of distinct elements exists. Basically, any time you want to continue some process "ad infinitum," and that process isn't completely well-defined (here we have many choices what e.g. $a_{17}$ should be), the axiom of choice is probably necessary.

Comment: Let me cough and suggest you re-read that very last sentence. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean, it's true . . . :P

Comment: That's better now. :-)